# Mithril.js: Should two child components talk to each other through their parent's controller?

Tags: mithril.js

I'm a bit stuck looking for the right way to do the following. I have a parent component with two child components (see simplified code below). I would like to know the proper way for `ChildA`, when its button is pressed, to 'invoke' `ChildB`. They should communicate through the parent, but should they communicate through their controllers? In that case the parent has to pass its controller to the controllers of the children.

```js
Parent = {
  view: function () {
    m.component(ChildA);
    m.component(ChildB);
  }
}

ChildA = {
  view: function () {
    m('button')
  }
}

ChildB = {
  view: function () {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really just a question of the plain javascript style you prefer. Think of communication between JS objects and how you would handle that.

Generally, Mithril devs choose between **Parent/Child** communication and **Pub/Sub**. For Parent/Children, the controller is commonly where devs place their logic. `m.component` accepts multiple parameters in which you can pass references (data/state/logic) to child components. [See the docs](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.component.html#parameterized-components). There's no need to pass Parent controllers to children.

However, I prefer to create a **view-model** which lives outside of any one component. It's where I keep view state (ie. form data) and view logic (ie. events, UI related callbacks, and shared state between components). This way, when I inevitably change/add components, I will not have to rework the controller logic in each component.

Leo Horie, the author of Mithril, [wrote an article](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/mapping-view-models.html) in which he explains communication between a Parent and One Child, but this can effortlessly be applied to multiple children.

Pub/Sub is a common JS idiom. The Mithril wiki lists a few community contributions that handle this. Go to [the wiki](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/wiki), open the page titled "All Topics" and do a normal page search for "pub". You'll discover a few options there. Depending on the complexity of your app, your next move might be to search for a Pub/Sub library through google.

Comment: Thanks pelón! Great info, this will certainly get me a long way in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess when you press the button of `ChildA`, some model state will be updated? Then, if both childs share the same model, the redraw done by Mithril after each event will update `ChildB` automatically.

My suggestion is to pass the model to the child objects and let `ChildA` also be a controller for the button. Why not the parent? Parents should usually handle commands that apply to multiple child views (or itself), and a button click seems simple/coupled enough for `ChildA` to manage that itself. But it depends on the real complexity of the system, of course. Always the problem with a simple example, it does not describe reality. :)

Here's an example how I mean anyway: http://jsbin.com/sipahe/edit?js,output

(Sorry for the Coffeescript, but it's brief and conveys the meaning very well.)

Comment: Thanks for the example. And it's great that you use Coffeescript since I'm using the related LiveScript myself. :)